# How many triangles with area 1 can be constructed using these 7 points?

Tags: combinatorics

How many triangles with area one can be constructed using these 7 points on the unit square lattice?

```
*
* * *
* * *
```

I found 12 using simple counting but it may cause a lot of errors. The answer is true but I want a mathematical way to count them.

Comment: With what area?

Comment: @MichaelBurr $1$

Comment: So each point is separated by $1$ unit right ?

Comment: To clarify: are those supposed to be the points $(0, 2), (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0)$? Or are they slightly perturbed from those locations, as the drawing might suggest?

Comment: This is a programming problem, rather than a mathematical one. I took the coordinates provided by John Hughes, made a set of all combinations of 3 points (there were $\binom73=35$ of those), and looked at the areas. There are 4 things with area $0$ (degenerate triangles, so to say), 16 triangles with area $1\over2$, 12 with area 1, one with area $3\over2$, and two with area $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First suppose that you do not use the top left vertex, then we want the triangles of maximum order which are $3+3$ ($3$ when the repeated vertices are in the bottom and another $3$ when the repeated vertices are on top).

Now lets count the triangles that use the vertex on the top left corner:

First count the triangles in which the other two vertices are in the same level, this gives us $3$ triangles.

After this we check the $3\times 3$ triangles in which the other two vertices are at different levels, this is a bit of casework but we can do it carefully and systematically.